# EKS AssumeRole operation: not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource role/eksClusterRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I try to create eks cluster following the AWS documentation 
i created the VPS and the cluster
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html
i created user joni with all permissions.
i created rule named eksClusterRole with all ask related policies
in Test your configuration section 2 
when running :

```
kubectl get svc
```

I'm getting :

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::444:user/joni is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::444:role/eksClusterRole
```

when executing to make sure I'm using joni user :

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

the result is :

```
{
    "UserId": "AIDA2J4I66QDJGWIZIMXC",
    "Account": "708419974150",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::444:user/joni"
}
```

ok i was reading the documentation and the links in google
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/
and here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#best-practice-managed-vs-inline
and i added inline policy to joni user : (allow all sts)

```
looks like this :
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "sts:*",
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and the configuration  .kube/config yml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMdEE2amRzU1BLTStnK005NW81dm1mV0pNNkJZaStGMDhOTHBrUQp5ZHd4MVpUVE9jaDIyaGNRMytCb0Fwb2VFTlNZazRkSGtpT2dCNlg3VUEzSlJpUWFUbElBbE1aRXdwZz0KLSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=
    server: https://xxxxxx.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:xxxxxx:cluster/eks-master
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:444:cluster/eks-master
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:444:cluster/eks-master
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:444:cluster/eks-master
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:444:cluster/eks-master
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:444:cluster/eks-master
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eks-master
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::444:role/eksClusterRole
      command: aws
```

what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you you got access to `arn:aws:iam::555:role/eksClusterRole` in the console?

Comment: sure i created it

Comment: What does that roles policy look like?

Comment: i have : AmazonEKSClusterPolicy and AmazonEKSServicePolicy

Comment: Is the role in a seperate account? You used `444` and `555`

Comment: my mistake, no they are the same say 444 , i will fix the question
how do i create EKS as IAM user XXX